# Как установить опцию в поле в jira post-function?(Groovy)

Tags: groovy, jira

Я пытаюсь установить опцию в поле(выпадающий список) в задаче jira при помощи Groovy.

Я написал код, но он ничего не обновляет , лишь очищает поле от предыдущего значения ПОЧЕМУ-ТО..
Скажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так ?

Мой код :

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption


def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();


def changeCf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("name cf")//cf 
issue.setCustomFieldValue(changeCf, "name value option") //option value
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я написал код, надеюсь это кому-нибудь поможет.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption

def currentUser = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.loggedInUser
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def optionsManger =ComponentAccessor.getOptionsManager()

def customField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectsByName("cf name").first()
def availableOptions = ComponentAccessor.optionsManager.getOptions(customField.getRelevantConfig(issue))
def optionToSet = availableOptions.find { it.value == "option name" }
return optionToSet

def config = customField.getRelevantConfig(issue)

issue.setCustomFieldValue(customField, option)
issueManager.updateIssue(currentUser, issue, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык